# How to watch for an Aside closing in angular-strap

Tags: angularjs, angular-strap

I'm using [angular-strap](https://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/) to show an Aside, and want to react to the user closing it (to cancel a background computation). This can easily be done if the user clicks on `x` or the close-button I added, but the user can also close the aside by clicking on the grayed-out background.

Is there any generic method to watch for the Aside closing?

`$destroy` is *not* emitted on the scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can listen for 'modal-hide' event:

```
$scope.$on('modal.hide', function() {
  console.log('modal-hide');
});
```

check out that plunker: 
http://plnkr.co/edit/f6l0KBMiSsknRpeXLo9P

Comment: I've just patched the lib to properly emit an `aside.hide` event. will be available for the next `v2.1.1` release.